# Mongoose populate() not working as desired

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have a PaymentCard and a User schema, and want to define an existing user's ID when creating a new PaymentCard record to link that specific card to a specific customer. It does create the PaymentCard document with the customer's mongoID, however querying with .populate() does not return any cards on any of the users, and return empty arrays on all users.

Comment: can you share the paymentcard and the user schema and how you conduct your query. Please show more code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to populate cards from user, you need to push the card id to the user cards array when you create a payment. But I don't see that logic in your `addPayment`.

Also, as already mentioned you need to correct your user schema, the ref must be `"PaymentCard"` for cards in the user schema. (And for the PaymentCard you need to correct ref for customer to the `"Customer"`)

To make things easy, I will exclude the jwt.verify parts, and describe my solution.

As I already said, you need to save the created card id to the user's cards array:

```js
router.post("/addPayment", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const result = await PaymentCard.create(req.body);

    const customerId = req.body.owner;

    const response = await Customer.findByIdAndUpdate(
      customerId,
      {
        $push: { cards: result._id } //result._id has the value of newly created card
      },
      { new: true }
    );

    res.send(response);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send("Something went wrong");
  }
});
```

Let's say you have this customer without any card:

```
{
    "cards": [],
    "_id": "5e823f6f76322539e0fb1668",
    "name": "John",
    "surname": "Smith",
    "customerStatus": "Regular",
    "email": "john@test.com",
    "phoneNo": "123123123",
    "__v": 0
}
```

When we add a card with our post route, this customer will be like this:

```
{
    "cards": [
        "5e82400776322539e0fb1669"
    ],
    "_id": "5e823f6f76322539e0fb1668",
    "name": "John",
    "surname": "Smith",
    "customerStatus": "Regular",
    "email": "john@test.com",
    "phoneNo": "123123123",
    "__v": 0
}
```

The added card document was:

```
{
    "owner": "5e823f6f76322539e0fb1668",
    "nameOnCard": "John Smith",
    "cardNumber":"1234123412341234",
    "cardIssuer": "VISA",
    "cvc": 123,
    "exp": 202008
}
```

Now you can populate the user's cards like this:

```
router.get("/getAll", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const customerId = "5e823f6f76322539e0fb1668";

    const result = await Customer.findById(customerId).populate("cards");

    res.send(result);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send("Something went wrong");
  }
});
```

This will give you the following result:

```
{
    "cards": [
        {
            "_id": "5e82400776322539e0fb1669",
            "owner": "5e823f6f76322539e0fb1668",
            "nameOnCard": "John Smith",
            "cardNumber": "1234123412341234",
            "cardIssuer": "VISA",
            "cvc": 123,
            "exp": 202008,
            "__v": 0
        }
    ],
    "_id": "5e823f6f76322539e0fb1668",
    "name": "John",
    "surname": "Smith",
    "customerStatus": "Regular",
    "email": "john@test.com",
    "phoneNo": "123123123",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you! Your method worked just perfectly!!
If you don't mind, would you care to explain why and how the logic in /addPayment that you gave me works how it works? Just trying to understand and learn here :)

Comment: @PRR to be able to populate cards from user, you need to save card ids in the cards array of user. Please don’t forget to mark as answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. The ref should be to the model and not the underlying collection, so in this case to `'PaymentCard'` rather than `'paymentcards'`.
2. Since you are going for an unbounded `1-N` relation this can be solved with mongoose [virtual properties](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/virtuals.html#populate).

On your `Customer` schema:

```
const Customer = new Schema({
...
});


Customer.virtual('cards', {
  ref: 'PaymentCard',
  localField: '_id',
  foreignField: 'owner',
  justOne: false
});

module.exports = ...
```

And then you can use `.populate('cards')` to get the contents of the virtual

Comment: I have tried referencing the model, however it still does not return anything inside the cards array for each user

Comment: Are you sure that the cards property on the customer contains anything? Or just the owner property in the PaymentCard? If this is the case i suspect you are looking for a [virtual property](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/virtuals.html#populate) rather than a ref for the cards array.

Comment: yes, whenever I make the POST request to register a new card and provide the mongoID of an existing user, it gets saved as ObjectID in the owner field in the new PaymentCard. However, the cards array on each of the customer stays empty in my GET call to get the list of customers, even with the populate() function

Comment: I think the problem is then that you are not updating the `cards` of the owner as well to include the new `PaymentCard`'s id. The populate is looking at the `cards` array to figure out what `PaymentCard` to connect to what id. If the array is empty then nothing will be populated. I updated my answer to include the `virtual` definition.

Comment: Hey. Using a virtual like you suggested throws ```Error: Virtual path "cards" conflicts with a real path in the schema```,  but when I remove the 'cards' field from the schema it does nothing and when getting a list of all users does not populate/include the array in the res

Comment: The virtual pretends to be defined on the model like a real property, so it replaces the previous property definition of cards. Also you still need the `.populate('cards')` call even with the virtual.

Comment: I am using .populate('cards') still and using the virtual, however the GET call only returns a list of users, and no mention of cards anywhere whatsoever

Comment: Can you try moving the `res.send` call into the exec callback?

Comment: That doesn't help